# Android preferences to allow file access to an apps sandboxed DOCUMENTS sub-folder?

Tags: android, ios, download, filesystems, symlink

By default, on both iOS and Android, apps can download files to app sub-directories; but those files are hidden from the user.  The app can see and access them, but users cannot.

On iOS, you can have some of your apps sandboxed sub-directories exposed to the user.  When the proper `info.plist` keys are applied, those specific sub-directories will appear in the iPhones `Files` app under `On My iPhone --> MyAppFolder`.  `MyAppFolder` is a symlink (alias) to the actual `/apps/MyApp/Documents` folder.  And anything that your app downloads into the /apps/MyApp/Documents folder is now visible to users.  The two keys required are:

```
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
<true/>
```

Is anything like this possible on Android?  I currently am downloading files to the users externalRootDirectory which places files directly into the users general `Downloads` folder.  But this method is dependent on a few things that is not guaranteed across all device types - as well, it could be a path/folder that Android removes access to in the future.

Does Android have any preferences or methods that allow sandboxed app folders to be exposed to the user similar to how iOS does it?  If so, what are the preferences or actions that need to be applied to make this happen?

Comment: Just create your own subfolder in public Download folder. There is no reason to believe that this public folder will disappear.

Comment: @blackapps -  I am trying to future proof my app.  In lengthy discussions with others regarding related subject we have found the following regarding Android: `Starting with API 33, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE will no longer work and instead they have READ_MEDIA_* permissions for images, audio, and video.`  So changes are coming to the external paths.  This means that DOCs, PDFs, Excl, etc wouldn't be accessible anymore.

Comment: Your conclusion just does not make sense. And if those files would not be accessable than what sense would it have to put them on your device? The new thing is that an app does not need the WRITE permission anymore as it is implicitly allowed to write to all public directories on external storage.